# How to check if port 1129 is enabled?

Tags: php

I am using the fistdata global api, I got the sample code in php. When I run that code i got an error message

> Failure could not connect

I want to know is port 1129 is enable or not in my site. How this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [online port scanner](http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$fp = @fsockopen($url,$port,$errno,$errstr,2);
if(!$fp)
{
    echo "Close.</br>";
}

    else{
    echo "Open.</br>";
    fclose($fp);
}
```